# How to run a java process in a separate thread

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I have a testing application. It has a mock service written in java. I need to keep on running this service through out the test suite in a separate thread. Besides that I need to stray this service before executing tests and tests are also written in java and testng.

Comment: Can you use `Thread`?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/threads.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If too many threads are going to be used then best way is to use java executor service as below.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    //Start your mock service
    }
});

executorService.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use `Thread` inside your application i recommend using lambda in order to run particular methods inside a new Thread `new Thread(() -> yourMethod()).start();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can use thread. I need to execute test cases and mock process in two different threads.